# Python - populate data from database at the same time everyday using Schedule

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks

I want to populate data from one data source to another every day. So, with a little bit of a research, I found "Schedule" so that I tried it. However, it didn't work in the way I expected. Hence, I'd like to know why and if there is any workaround to achieve my goal.

Below are example of my code in Pyhton3.

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import schedule
import time

postgre_engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://user1:pass1@srever_ip/db_name1')
mysql_engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://user2:pass2@server_ip2:port_no/db_name2')


def job():

    # get data from mysql
    query = ('SELECT * '
                'FROM table1 '
                'WHERE event_date_time > CURRENT_DATE - 1 '
                'AND event_date_time < CURRENT_DATE '
             )

    df = pd.read_sql(query, mysql_engine)

    # write back to postgres
    postgre_table = 'table2'
    df.to_sql(postgre_table, postgre_engine, if_exists='append', index=False) 


schedule.every().day.at("07:30").do(job)
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

I've always got `NameError: name 'df' is not defined`. Is there any other ways that can make the scheduled query works?

Comment: I feel that your are using `schedule` in the correct way. Is it possible that the error is due to the fact that your mysql query fails? The error suggests that you are not creating the dataframe.

Comment: @Valentino it kinda skipped everything else along the way as it tried to print something out in my code and went straightaway to  `df.to_sql(blah, blah, blah)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you work with a Unix system, you could utilize [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron). To add a new cronjob for your current user use

```
crontab -e
```

Then, within the editor determined by the environment variable `$EDITOR` you can add a new line that executes every day at 7:30

```
30 7 * * * /path/to/your/script
```

Your script would have to be adapted to execute the `job` function everytime it is called and the `schedule` parts removed.